# Cubic Bézier radius of curvature calculation

Tags: matlab, parametric, curvature, bezier-curve

I modelled a racetrack using cubic Bézier curves. I understand that the representation is parametric: x and y vary with t. I have successfully created the cartesian coordinates thanks to this: https://blogs.mathworks.com/graphics/2014/10/13/bezier-curves/

Now I'm trying to calculate the radius of the curvature at each of the x points I have created. I would like to use [this expression](https://www.intmath.com/applications-differentiation/8-radius-curvature.php) to calculate the radii (I think this is the easiest way to do this, if there is a simpler way, please feel free to let me know).

Here is how I plan on doing this:

1/ Use the y(t) function for every curve (p24 of [this PDF](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-837-computer-graphics-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT6_837F12_Lec01.pdf))

2/ Evaluate it at every t

I should have the curvature for every x,y point, right? I'm worried about the 'scaling': t varies between 0 and 1 but x varies between way higher values (for example between 300 and 555). Isn't this going to make the calculation of the radius false?

Thank you very much in advance for your precious help,

Regards,
LD

Answer (score 3):

That formula is great when $y$ can be written as a function of $x$, but that doesn't work in cases where the assumption fails...for things like, say, an oval racetrack, where there are two $y$-values for every $x$-value, or for any more generic curve that might contain a vertical line segment (e.g., a Bezier!).

Instead, you want to use the parametric curvature formula:
$$
k(t) = \frac{x''(t) y'(t) - y''(t)x'(t)} {(x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
$$

(This formula assumes that the curve goes counterclockwise; if your curve goes clockwise, then you need to negate it.)

The radius of curvature is then $1/k(t)$.

The only problem arises when the denominator in $k$ is zero, which happens only when both the $x$ and $y$ derivatives are zero, i.e., when the curve is not "regular"; in this case, you get a $0/0$ form, and the formula's no good to you. In your project, it seems to me that this is unlikely to happen.

Of course, you're **inverting** $k$, so you'll have a problem if 
$$
x''(t) y'(t) - y''(t)x'(t) = 0
$$
at some time $t$; again, I expect this not to be a problem unless your racetrack has some long "straightaway," where the radius of curvature is infinite.

Here's a bit of sample code to show you what's going on.

```
function sillycurve()
% Here's an example of the code for you. It actually has the "denominator = 0"
% problem, which I've addressed (crudely) here by adding .001 to the
% denominator, just so you can see the problem nicely. 

clear;
clf;
N = 300; % use 300 points
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);
dt = 2*pi/N; 
% Substitute any formula you like for x and y below. 
x = sin(t);
y = cos(2*t) - cos(t);
figure(1); 
% Show the curve, growing...
for i=[1:10:N]
    plot(x(1:i), y(1:i));
    set(gca, 'XLim', [min(x), max(x)], 'YLim', [min(y), max(y)])
    figure(gcf);
    pause(0.1);
end

figure(gcf);
% 
% Compute $x'(t)$ and $x''(t)$, etc. 
xp =  (circshift(x,  1) - x )/dt;
xpp = (circshift(xp, 1) - xp)/dt;
yp =  (circshift(y,  1) - y )/dt;
ypp = (circshift(yp, 1) - yp)/dt;

% Numerator and denominator for curvature formula
kn = xpp .* yp - ypp .* xp;
kd = (xp.^2 + yp.^2).^1.5 + .001; % the .001 is added to avoid divide-by-zero problems

% A plot of the denominator, so that you can see where it goes to zero:
figure(2); 
plot(t, kd); 
figure(gcf);

% And finally, a plot of the curvature
k = kn ./ kd; 
R = 1 ./ k;

figure(3);
plot(t, k);
figure(gcf);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, I already know that some curves are pure straights... I'm starting to think that using cartesian coordinates might not be the best of ideas. I saw a few people use curvilinear coordinates and obtain the curvature from those. Would it be easier? I have never used said coordinates...

Comment: Well, if you've got straight line segments, then the radius of curvature, along those segments, is infinity. Changing coordinate systems isn't going to change that, as curvature is an implicit notion, independent of coordinates!

Comment: If I get infinite values, that's okay. If the code crashes, that's a problem. If x'(t) y''(t) - y'(t)x''(t)=0, then the radius is infinite, right? If that condition is true, then I could skip the rest of the calculation and directly say that the result (the radius) is equal to inf. But will the radius value be correct the rest of the time? This method requires the formula to be evaluated at t, not at the real x point. Will that cause an issue?

Comment: That's almost right. If $x'(t) = y'(t) = 0$ as well, then you've got $0/0$, which is an indeterminate form. I very much doubt this will happen. For "the rest of the time," the formula is indeed correct. You're correct that you need the $t$-value in addition to $x$ and $y$. Since you used $t$ to compute $x$ and $y$, you *could* just store it in an additional field, i.e., you could compute $(x, y, t)$ points, but plot just the $x$- and $y$-coordinates. Then you'd have $t$ around when you need it to compute the curvature. (Or you could compute, at each point, $(x, y, t, k, R)$ and be done!)

Comment: Additionally, I could use a polynomial curve fitting function to approximate the cartesian polynomial. But what should be the order of such a polynomial? In other words, if we have a cubic Bézier (order 4), then could the output in cartesian coordinates be also approximated by a 4th order polynomial?

Comment: I replied before I could have a chance to read your comment. Basically, every time either the numerator or the denominator is equal to zero, the radius should be infinite, right? So instead of checking if only one is equal to zero, I think I can safely add the second one to the test condition. Last thing, and I don't want to sound rude or anything, I just don't quite get the maths... If I approximate using t, isn't the radius going to be false? In my head, it would be like calculating the radius with a very small x (0 to 1 instead of 300 to 555), which should have an effect on the results?

Comment: 1. I have no idea what you're talking about with the curve-fitting question, so I'm not going to try to answer. 2. Your conclusion about the radius being infinite when either the numerator or denominator is zero is wrong. When the numerator *only* is zero, the radius is infinite. When both are zero, you don't know what the radius is (and indeed, there may be no radius of curvature!). In all other cases, the formula really WILL give the correct answer, yes. When you say "approximate using $t$", there's no approximation going on -- just a different way of defining a curve!

Comment: I've added code to demonstrate the formula at work (including the possible problems).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a code for me. I really mean it, thank you! I am now sure that using the parametric curvature formula is the way to go. Let me just ask you one more question:It's still about that t. OK, so it's only a way of defining the curve, I understand. So calculating the radius using t will return the same results as if I were to calculate the radius of the polynomial representing the Bezier curve in the x,y coordinates, correct? I'm sorry to keep bothering you with the same question over and over. I just want to be sure it's not going to interfere with the results

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: suppose we graph $y = f(x)$, where $f$ is your polynomial (assuming there is one!). We can parameterize this graph via $t \mapsto (t, f(t))$, right? It gets us exactly the same points. We have $x(t) = t, y(t) = f(t)$, so $x'(t) = 1$ and $x''(t) = 0$. PLug that into my formula, and you get $\frac{-f''(t)}{(1 + f'(t)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$...which is exactly the formula you were using. So your formula is a special case of the one I wrote down (up to a sign, which is always a problem...)

Comment: Thank you so much once again for the time you take to explain me things. I get it now. I have tried your code with my Bezier curve (by changing x and y as well as dt and I am obtaining strange results: Sometimes when the curve is straight, the radius suddenly becomes close to infinity for no apparent reason. I will work on the code a bit more and probably upload it here if I haven't solved this glitch... But still it seems to be working a lot better than it used to.

Comment: When the curve is straight, the radius of curvature *is* infinity, so you should expect it (in a numerical-mathematics setting where everything is approximate) to be "near" infinity, i.e., very large (either positive OR negative).